# Fork-join task on the single-proccesor system

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm going throught the [Java Tutorial about Fork-join taksks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) and wht it says is:

> You can take advantage of concurrent processing on multiprocessor
>   systems by implementing the algorithm using the fork/join framework.

It's reasonable to ask whether we can take such an advantage on a single-processor system? To me, it's just not quite clear from the definition of Fork-Join?

Comment: It's a multi-threading framework - you do the maths.

Comment: @BoristheSpider What did you try to say? Yes, I'm going to do some computations using that framework in order to improve performance. I have around 500 task needed to proceed, but the thing is I'm going to perform the tasks on a single-processor environment.Does it ever make a sense to try to use this framework?

Comment: No, of course not. It's a framework for multi-threading. You don't have multiple threads. It will almost certainly be catastrophic for performance.

Comment: @BoristheSpider So, I can create a few threads to perform the task in multiple threads. As far as I understood it can improve the entire task's performance.

Comment: Sorry. You have a **single** CPU. It can perform a **single** task at a time. Unless you have multiple cores. If you can only do **one thing** at a time, then splitting your tasks into multiple bits to be executed concurrently only adds the overhead of splitting. In the worst case, you are also going to incur the extra context switching on your single CPU. In the best case you are only going to incur the extra cost of splitting the job.

Comment: @BoristheSpider In our production environment we have 8-cores processor, as far as I know. So would it be useful to use multiple threads or it doesn't depends on the number of cores?

Comment: You said "single processor system", this is a system with one core. You are now saying that you have an eight processor system. In which case, yes: multi-threading makes sense. But you should of course benchmark the alternatives.

Comment: You said "I have 500 *tasks*"---if you're considering Fork/Join, it doesn't matter how many tasks you have. F/J is about parallelizing *one task at a time*. You may just want a plain `ExecutorService` instead.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I meant I can split one big task into around 500 smaller tasks. That's why I want to use parallelism.

Comment: And does each individual task take more than 1 millisecond to compute? That's about the breakeven point where the overhead of splitting and thread handoff begins to pay off.